# Separating static and time-dependent components of E and B

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations

I have been wrestling with Maxwell's equations using a source term in which both charge density and current density are time-independent functions of position, and where current is considered to be equal to charge density multiplied by “charge velocity”.  Clearly, the divergence of the current density (i.e., the charge density times the charge velocity) must equal zero in order to ensure that  charge density is time-independent.

Where I'm running into a problem is in proving that the solution of Maxwell's equations then consists of two components: a time-dependent component that is independent of the source terms, and a time-independent  (static) component that depends on the source terms.

I'm sure there are standard, straightforward ways to do this, but my attempts so far are unsuccessful.

What I've come up with are these equations (setting all constants = 1):

$$\nabla^2E – \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^2}E = -\nabla \rho$$
and
$$\nabla^2B – \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^2}B = -\nabla   \times \vec j)$$

I *think* separating E and B into time-dependent and time-independent components will show that a time-independent charge and current distribution cannot produce EM radiation.

Is it legitimate *in general* to write:
$$\vec E = \vec E_{rad} + \vec E_{static}$$

where $$\vec E_{rad}$$ satisfies
$$\nabla^2 \vec E_{rad} – \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^2} \vec E_{rad} = 0$$

and

$$ \nabla^2 \vec E_{static}(\vec x) = -\nabla \rho (\vec x)?$$

And, if so, then does that prove there is no EM radiation produced by a time-independent distribution of charge and current?

Comment: The idea is just fine, but trying to solve the differential equations directly is a pain. It's easier to solve for the potentials (not too hard when everything is time-independent) and then use those to get the fields. The results will be the time-independent case of [Jefimenko's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations), to which you can add an arbitrary solution to the wave equation.

Comment: What boundary conditions do you set for these equations?

Comment: The boundary conditions are that $ρ$ and $j⃗ $ are confined to a finite region, and that both are time-independent.  @knzhou, thanks for the link to Jefimeko's equations.  Am I right that E and B can *in general* be separated into time-dependent parts that satisfy the wave equations and time-independent parts that satisfy e.g. my last equation when  $ρ$ and $j⃗ $ meet my conditions?

Comment: Yes it is fine, the only thing is you have taken a particular gauge of choice, the full relationship consists of a relativistic mixed equation, with Dirac matrices under geometric algebra, this look like ∇_μv E = ∂_μv ⋅ E + (∂_μv B/∂t)^k γ_kγ_0
= ∂_μv ⋅ E + iσ ⋅ (Γ_μv x E)^k γ_k γ_0
= ∂_μv ⋅ E + (∂Ω_μv/∂t)^k a_k

Comment: I imagine you're right that it is fine, but can you provide a reference? It might be more of a math question than a physics question.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/220/handouts/section_4_2_Maxwells_Equations_for_Electrostatics_package.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjfgOGPubrmAhWPi1wKHY1gAOgQFjAPegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw2d7VILswu5x6pLX1WNnJSY

Comment: Looks like that link explains Maxwell's equations in the static case, without addressing the issue I'm asking about.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the issue? I already said what you have done is fine. The reference is related to what you have stated, using slightly different notation.

Comment: If it is the last statement, there are many instances of static fields that do not radiate away so easily. This is by our best guesses brought on by many different circumstances such as related to the zeno effect where the wave function evolution is effectively disabled in some given finite time, or an electron oscillating in the ground state will not give up radiation. electromagnetic field is a magnetic field produced by moving electrically charged objects. They have zero Hertz.

Comment: My question is not so much about physics, as about the propriety of a specific mathematical procedure. Specifically, I'd like to know if it is appropriate in the general time independent source (charge/current density) case to represent E and B as the sums of time-dependent wave field components and time-independent components, to solve for the two separately, and then to assert that the general solution (in this case) is a linear sum of the two separate solutions.  "What you did is fine" is encouraging, but doesn't tell me *why* it's fine.  A link to a math justification would serve nicely.

Comment: Something along the lines of what @knzhou commented, but with an explanation of why it is okay to "add an arbitrary solution to the wave equation."  My intuition says it's okay, but I'm hoping for something more rigorous.  It's obvious that the sum is a *valid* solution, but not obvious to me (yet) that the sum is indeed the general solution.

Answer (score -1):

This looks OK. There are many instances we would take a total quantity of something by separating it into static and non-static parts.